# fancyBox2 iframe selector differences from parent

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I try to apply fancyBox2 on elements inside an iframe from the parent.
Therefore I want to use the following selector:

```
$('a.lightbox', $('#modal iframe').contents()).fancybox();
```

But this selector is not working. In contrast to that, the following selector is working:

```
$('#modal iframe').contents().find('a.lightbox').fancybox();
```

The first selector is even working with other kind of functions, e.g.:

```
$('a.lightbox', $('#modal iframe').contents()).addClass('hidden');
```

Why is that the case? What's the difference?

Comment: For what I see, the difference is that you don't have the fancybox js files inside the iframed page so cannot bind that selector to it.

Comment: The js files from fancyBox2 are included in the iframed page, so this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference?

This :

```
$('a.lightbox', $('#modal iframe').contents());
```

... is a shortcut (sometimes referred as shorthand) of this :

```
$('#modal iframe').contents().find('a.lightbox');
```

... which it means that when you execute the first (shortcut), the second is invoked.

Shortcuts help to speed up and simplify coding but in terms of performance it's always better to use direct methods or functions.

For instance, if you have three elements sharing the same selector like :

```
<a class="fancybox">...</a>
<a class="fancybox">...</a>
<a class="fancybox">...</a>
```

these will produce the same result :

```
var counter1 = $("html").find(".fancybox").length;          // returns 3
var counter2 = $(".fancybox", $("html")).length;            // returns 3
var counter3 = $(".fancybox", $("html").contents()).length; // returns 3
```

> Why is that the case? (or why it does or doesn't work?)

It depends on many factors like where and when (the context) you are manipulating the DOM, but when working with *iframes* you have to make sure that :

- the *iframe* contests are fully loaded
- you bind events when the DOM (inside the iframe) is ready

For consistency (and cross-browser compatibility, I would dare to say) I would use the `.load()` method to verify the *iframe* contents are fully loaded and the `.each()` method to iterate through the selectors I want to manipulate or *bind* events like :

```
$('#modal iframe').load(function () {
    // iframe is loaded, then
    var that = $(this); // the iframe element     
    that.contents().find('a.lightbox')
    .each(function () {
        $(this) // the lightbox selector
        // bind events or manipulate elements
        .addClass("whatever")
        .fancybox();
    });
});
```

Or if you prefer the shortcut format :

```
$('#modal iframe').load(function () {
    // iframe is loaded, then
    var that = $(this); // the iframe element     
    $('a.lightbox', that.contents()) // shortcut format
    .each(function () {
        $(this) // the lightbox selector
        // bind events or manipulate elements
        .addClass("whatever")
        .fancybox();
    });
});
```

They should work equally well in any browser. **[HERE is a DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/bindSelectorsToFancyboxIframedPage_20mar15.html)**  using the shortcut format.